# Problem with update query while inserting foreign key value in database column

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am working on a cms for properties in oop php for learning purposes. I have a gallery with images for each individual property. Now I am trying to get one of those images to be main image for that specific property. I have three tables.

```
properties (id, location, price, main_photo_id)

property_photo (id, property_id, photo_id)

photos (id, name, extension)
```

I am having trouble to write query that will update main_photo_id column (properties table) with id from photos table (or photo_id from property_photo table, it is the same basically). I know that query isn't good because it always writes 0 in main_photo_id column, but I am relatively unexperienced in sql and can't seem to find the problem. Any help is appreciated.

AdModel:

```
public function MainPhotoInsert($photoid)
{   
    $this->db->query('UPDATE properties INNER JOIN photos ON photos.id = properties.id SET properties.main_photo_id = :main_photo_id');     
    $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id', $photoid);
    $this->db->execute();
}
```

AdsController:

```
public function galleryAction()
 {
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $photo_id = $_SESSION['photo_id'];
    } else {
        $photo_id = $_GET['id'];
    }


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

        if(isset($_POST['radio']))
        {
            $this->AdModel->MainPhotoInsert($photoid);
            redirect('ads/index');
        }   
    }

    $data = $this->AdModel->getPhotosForProperty($photo_id);
    $data1 = $this->AdModel->MainPhotoData($photo_id);

    $this->view->render('ads/gallery', $data, $data1);
 }
```

gallery.php

```
<form action="/ads/gallery?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
  <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) : ?>   
        <img src="<?php echo '/public/photos/'.$value->name.'.'.$value->extension ?>" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" width="250" height="250">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $value->photo_id; ?>" >Make main
    <br>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "properties in OOP" as in "houses", not "fields of objects".

Comment: @KIKOSoftware as in houses, flats, ads if you like. sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: Why not keep the update query simple? `UPDATE properties SET main_photo_id = :main_photo_id WHERE id = :property_id;`. You need two fields: The property and the photo ids.

Comment: It's unfortunate that [properties have a meaning in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). It's not your English.

Comment: @MER Yeah, but how would I then get id from photos table that corresponds to this foreign key?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I would have to change that through the whole application. Can it be done with current tables?

Comment: I think your `AdModel` object should have the `property_id`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195196/discussion-between-marko-and-kiko-software).

Comment: Sorry, got a phone call, so couldn't chat.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  Can it be done with this?  public function MainPhotoInsert($photoid)
    {   
        $this->db->query('UPDATE properties LEFT JOIN photos ON properties.main_photo_id = photos.id SET :main_photo_id = photos.id');     
        $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id', $photoid);
        $this->db->execute();
    }

Comment: No, that is an invalid query. You cannot assign a value to a binded value/variable.

Comment: Do you have something like [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net)? You can use it to test your queries before you put them in PHP code (make sure to make a backup of your database, in case you make a mistake).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I have phpmyadmin. I will use it. Can you help about this query?

Comment: I've already told you what I think the query should be. Input is the property id and photo id. Query is: `UPDATE properties SET main_photo_id = :main_photo_id WHERE id = :property_id;`, Let me work on an alternative. One moment please.

Answer (score 1):

I have suggested to use this query:

```
UPDATE properties SET main_photo_id = :main_photo_id WHERE id = :property_id;
```

But that requires you to know the property id. I see now that you have the property id in the property_photo table so you could also use that:

```
public function MainPhotoInsert($photoid)
{   
    $subQuery = "SELECT property_id 
                 FROM property_photo 
                 WHERE id = :main_photo_id2";
    $this->db->query("UPDATE properties 
                      SET main_photo_id = :main_photo_id1
                      WHERE id = ($subQuery)");     
    $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id1', $photoid);
    $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id2', $photoid);
    $this->db->execute();
}
```

I'm using a subquery to find the id of the property and therefore I need to bind the photo id twice.

Note: I'm not sure but Mysql might get confused by the usage of an `id` from two different tables. If you get an error use aliasses like this:

```
public function MainPhotoInsert($photoid)
{   
    $subQuery = "SELECT B.property_id 
                 FROM property_photo AS B 
                 WHERE B.id = :main_photo_id2";
    $this->db->query("UPDATE properties AS A
                      SET A.main_photo_id = :main_photo_id1
                      WHERE A.id = ($subQuery)");     
    $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id1', $photoid);
    $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id2', $photoid);
    $this->db->execute();
}
```

All code is untested.

Comment: I tried query with aliasses but nothing changes in database in column main_photo_id in properties table. And I don't get this main_photo_id1 and main_photo_id2, from where did you find those, what are they?

Comment: I added $this->db->query in $subquery to work, and now it says this error  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: By adding `$this->db->query` in `$subquery` you completely changed the query, so that won't work. The `main_photo_id1` and `main_photo_id2` represent the same photo id, as you can see. I use them because I need the photo id twice and it might not be allowed to reuse the same binded id in a query. Finally, this query will only work if the photo id belongs to the property, if it doesn't nothing will change.

Comment: I deleted that code in $subquery., I realised that mistake. And photo_id does belong to the property. I just don't know why it won't update main_photo_id column?

Comment: I think there was a bug in the routine with the aliasses. I did not add the aliasses before every column. I've edited the code now. Can you try again? The query is correct, I think, but I can't test it myself, so I cannot be sure of the code.

Comment: It works like a charm in phpmyadmin. I get the correct photo_id in main_photo_id column. Just doesn't work when I enter it through form. I will try now edited code to see if it works

Comment: I added the edited code, it doesn't work. With php my admin works fine but with this it doesn't. I just don't get it :)

Comment: Well, the last thing I can think of is the `db->bind()`. I don't recognize it. Can it be found in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en)? Is it your own code? What does it do? I think it should work, because you reported an error earlier when you had two bound variables but only one parameter in the query...

Comment: It is my own code, but basically does the same as bind in pdo. I mean that works through the whole application, doesn't have reason to not work in this. In any case, thank you a lot for your time I will try to make it work with this.

Comment: Good luck with it.

Comment: I found the problem. It is in $subqeury. It returns property_id only if photo_id and ID of property_table are the same otherwise returns null. I can't have that. Do you know some workaround?

Comment: No, I don't know a workaround. What you're saying doesn't make sense.... in other words: I don't understand it. The subquery is a very simple select. It selects a row from `property_photo` based on the photo id and returns the `property_id` in that row. That `property_id` is then used in the main query to set the `main_photo_id` in the `properties` table.

Comment: When I try query in php admin like this SELECT B.property_id FROM property_photo AS B WHERE B.id = 95  where 95 is ID of some photo from column photo_id, query returns property_id column but with no results. It only returns result in property_id column when ID of property_photo and photo_id are the same number. Am I doing something wrong? I'm really confused

Comment: I'm confused as well, I don't understand what you're saying. Sorry, I can't help you.